# Google sql not inserting

Tags: php, mysql, google-app-engine

I'm having a very strange problem with Google SQL using `MySQL`. The `PHP` form doesn't seem to be executing so no SQL insert statements are working, yet I can't see a reason why - it was working fine up until yesterday. Here's the `PHP` code:

```
if(isset($_POST['email'])){
    $dsn = getenv('MYSQL_DSN');
    $user = getenv('MYSQL_USER');
    $password = getenv('MYSQL_PASSWORD');
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    syslog(LOG_INFO, 'EMAIL: ' . $email);

    $referral = "";

    if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {

        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO testEmails (email, referral) VALUES (:email, :referral)");

        if(isset($_POST['referral'])){
            $referral = filter_var($referral, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        }
        else{
            $referral = NULL;
        }

        $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
        $stmt->bindParam(':referral', $referral);
        $stmt->execute();

        echo "DONE";
    }
}
```

I've added `sysLog` to track emails inputted and it's not showing any email in the logger on `Google Cloud Platform`.

I can insert into the MySQL db via Cloud Shell. I receive the words "DONE" on screen so there doesn't seem to be a PHP error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: is the `DSN` correct? Does the `$stmt` get created successfully?

Comment: surely `$referral = filter_var($referral, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);` should be `$referral = filter_var($_POST['referral'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid programming error. Forgot to adjust SQL statement after creating new column that had a non-null value.